# how to track the application activity in iphone app

Tags: iphone, android-activity, tracking

I am making an app i want to track the activity of the user.For example if user selects any songs list then activity it shows user selected list and then if he selects any other then it should track all the activity of the app being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refer below third party libraries :

1) [Google Analytics.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/)

2) [Flurry Analytics.](http://www.flurry.com/)

3) [More](http://list.ly/list/Ff-list-of-mobile-analytics-tools)